# How to create Account, Contact and User

Tags: apex

I am trying to set up the system to verify if the account exists or not and to then create the account, then to do the same with the Contact, then to create a user.

I keep hitting one wall after another when doing this. My code is below. Please help.

First Error is:

> We can’t log you in because of the following error. For more information, contact your Salesforce administrator.
>
> ERROR_CREATING_USER: DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): User, original object: Contact

Code is below:

```
global class AgFinitiRegHandler implements Auth.RegistrationHandler{

    private profile userprofile;


     global User createUser(Id portalId, Auth.UserData data)
     {
        System.debug(logginglevel.DEBUG, 'CreateUser Auth.UserData: ' + data);

        string UserEpicorCompanyID  = data.AttributeMap.get('EpicorCompanyId');
        string UserDealerID         = data.AttributeMap.get('DealerId');
        string UserDealerRole       = data.AttributeMap.get('DealerRole');
        string UserAccountName      = data.AttributeMap.get('AccountName');
        string accountID;
        string contactID;
        User newUser;
         
        List<Account> Account = [select id from account where Epicor_Company__c = :UserEpicorCompanyID and AccountNumber = :UserDealerID Limit 1];
        System.debug(logginglevel.DEBUG, 'Account: ' + Account);
        if (Account.isEmpty())
        {
            System.debug(logginglevel.DEBUG, 'No Account found: ');
            //Create Account
            try
            {
                Account a = new Account(name = UserAccountName, AccountNumber = UserDealerID, Epicor_Company__c = UserEpicorCompanyID);
                insert a;
                System.debug(logginglevel.DEBUG, 'Attempted Account creation: ' + a.ID);
                accountID = a.ID;
            }
            catch(DMLException e)
            {
                System.debug(logginglevel.DEBUG, 'Issue creating account');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            accountID = Account.get(0).ID;
            System.debug(logginglevel.DEBUG, 'Account found: ');
        }
        
        //Check Contact
        List<Contact> Contact = [select id from contact where AccountID = :accountID and LastName = :data.LastName and FirstName = :data.FirstName Limit 1];
        System.debug(logginglevel.DEBUG, 'Contact: ' + Contact);
        if (Contact.isEmpty())
        {
            System.debug(logginglevel.DEBUG, 'No Contact found: ');
            //Create Contact
            try
            {
                Contact c = new Contact(AccountId = accountID, LastName = data.LastName, FirstName = data.FirstName, Email = data.email);
                insert c;
                System.debug(logginglevel.DEBUG, 'Contact Created: ' + c.ID);
                contactID = c.ID;
            }
            catch(DMLException e)
            {
                System.debug(logginglevel.DEBUG, 'Contact Creation Failed');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.debug(logginglevel.DEBUG, 'Contact found: ');
        } 
        
        UserRole ur=[select Id from UserRole where Name='TESTRole'];
        userprofile = getProfileID(UserDealerRole);
        
        User u = new User();
        u.email = data.email;  
        u.username = u.email;
        u.FirstName = data.FirstName;
        u.LastName = data.LastName;
        u.ContactID = contactID;
        
        u.AgFiniti_Dealer_Role__c = UserDealerRole;
        u.AgFiniti_ID__c = data.identifier;
        u.username = u.email;
        String alias = data.email;
        
        //Alias must be 8 characters or less
        integer AtSymbolPtr = alias.indexOf('@');
        
        if(AtSymbolPtr < 8) 
        {
            alias = alias.substring(0, AtSymbolPtr - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            alias = alias.substring(0, 8);
        }
        
        u.alias = alias;
        u.languagelocalekey = UserInfo.getLocale();
        u.localesidkey = UserInfo.getLocale();
        u.emailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
        u.timeZoneSidKey = 'America/Chicago';
        u.ProfileId = userprofile.Id;
        u.UserRoleID = ur.id;
        insert u;
        newUser = u;
        
        return newUser; 
              
     }
     
    global void updateUser(Id userId, Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){
    
        System.debug(logginglevel.DEBUG, 'Update User Auth.UserData: ' + data);

        string UserDealerRole       = data.AttributeMap.get('DealerRole');
        User u = new User(id=userId);
        
        u.FirstName = data.FirstName;
        u.LastName = data.LastName;
        u.email = data.email;
        u.Username = data.email;
        u.AgFiniti_Dealer_Role__c = UserDealerRole;
        
        System.debug(logginglevel.DEBUG, 'Updating User: ' + u);
        update(u);
    
        }
 
        private Profile getProfileID(string UserDealerRole)
        {
            if (UserDealerRole.startsWithIgnoreCase('Internal') == true)
            {
                userprofile = [SELECT Id FROM profile WHERE name='Standard User'];
            }
            else 
            {
                userprofile = [SELECT Id FROM profile WHERE name='Customer Community User'];
            }
            return userprofile;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Put your creation of `User` records within a `system.runAs` block.

> ## [Mixed DML Operations in Test Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects_test_methods.htm)
>
> Test methods allow for performing mixed Data Manipulation Language (DML) operations that include both setup sObjects and other sObjects if the code that performs the DML operations is enclosed within System.runAs method blocks. You can also perform DML in an asynchronous job that your test method calls. These techniques enable you, for example, to create a user with a role and other sObjects in the same test.
>   The setup sObjects are listed in sObjects That Cannot Be Used Together in DML Operations.
>
> #### Example: Mixed DML Operations in System.runAs Blocks
>
> This example shows how to enclose mixed DML operations within System.runAs blocks to avoid the mixed DML error. The System.runAs block runs in the current user’s context. It creates a test user with a role and a test account, which is a mixed DML operation.
>
> ```
> @isTest
> private class MixedDML {
>     static testMethod void mixedDMLExample() {  
>         User u;
>         Account a;
>         User thisUser = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
>        // Insert account as current user
>         System.runAs (thisUser) {
>             Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];
>             UserRole r = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole WHERE Name='COO'];
>             u = new User(alias = 'jsmith', email='jsmith@acme.com', 
>                 emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='Smith', 
>                 languagelocalekey='en_US', 
>                 localesidkey='en_US', profileid = p.Id, userroleid = r.Id,
>                 timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', 
>                 username='jsmith@acme.com');
>             insert u;
>             a = new Account(name='Acme');
>             insert a;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

If you keep reading this article you will see an approach that works *outside* test methods:

> #### Use @future to Bypass the Mixed DML Error in a Test Method
>
> Mixed DML operations within a single transaction aren’t allowed. You
>   can’t perform DML on a setup sObject and another sObject in the same
>   transaction. However, you can perform one type of DML as part of an
>   asynchronous job and the others in other asynchronous jobs or in the
>   original transaction. This class contains an @future method to be
>   called by the class in the subsequent example.
>
> ```
> public class InsertFutureUser {
>     @future
>     public static void insertUser() {
>         Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];
>         UserRole r = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole WHERE Name='COO'];
>         User futureUser = new User(firstname = 'Future', lastname = 'User',
>             alias = 'future', defaultgroupnotificationfrequency = 'N',
>             digestfrequency = 'N', email = 'test@test.org',
>             emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8', languagelocalekey='en_US', 
>             localesidkey='en_US', profileid = p.Id, 
>             timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
>             username = 'futureuser@test.org',
>             userpermissionsmarketinguser = false,
>             userpermissionsofflineuser = false, userroleid = r.Id);
>         insert(futureUser);
>     }
> }
> ```

Unfortunately using this approach means you will no longer be able to return the `User` record being created so you will have to change your method signature.

Answer (score 1):

User records and other records cannot be created and/or updated during the same transaction, mainly because this could lead to permissions conflicts (for example, if the new `UserRole` would not have access to the sObject that is being modified).  Since your `createUser` method returns the user created, I'm guessing your process requires the new User record for the rest of its logic.  As asynchronous processes are different transactions, you can create [`Queueable`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm) classes to process your records.  Unlike future methods, Queueable methods can be chained together, so you can queue your user creation, and in turn your user creation can chain another queueable class with the rest of your logic.